# How to make step response of exp function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
G = exp(-s) * (0.8*s^2+s+2)/(s^2+s);
T = feedback(ss(G),1);
step(T)
```

this is example from Matlab's documentation, but it's not working, when copy and paste to program, even if I declare that 's' is syms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `s` using

```
s = tf('s');
```

Comment: @kspacja: Thanks for accepting my answer. Definitely a lack in the MATLAB documentation.